# VS 2022 CodeAnalysis CS8032 error on compile

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I have a VS2022 project that worked perfect 3 days before, and then it stopped compiling with the following error:

**Error CS8032  An instance of analyzer Amazon.SimpleNotificationService.CodeAnalysis.PropertyValueAssignmentAnalyzer cannot be created from C:\Users\wasyster.nuget\packages\awssdk.simplenotificationservice\3.7.101.71\analyzers\dotnet\cs\AWSSDK.SimpleNotificationService.CodeAnalysis.dll : Method 'get_SupportedDiagnostics' in type 'Amazon.SimpleNotificationService.CodeAnalysis.PropertyValueAssignmentAnalyzer' from assembly 'AWSSDK.SimpleNotificationService.CodeAnalysis, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation..**

A did not add any new packages, I was working on some bug fix.
Then I tried some other projects and I got the **CodeAnalysis CS8032 error**.

What is interesting I reinstalled my whole OP system, a new VS 2022 instance, and the error remains.
I am on the latest Win10, and the latest VS 2022 Professional.

If needed I can provide any additional code sample.

Comment: There are a few questions with solutions with this issue in Stackoverflow. Did you check them?

Comment: Yes I did, and none helped me.

Answer (score 1):

After running manny rounds we figured out that VS 2022 17.6 is not compactibile with the AWSSDK.SimpleNotificationService Version 3.7.101.76.

On VS 2022 v17.5 works prefect.